# How Can I Get Information From An A Tag Between Two Span Tags in BeautifulSoup Using Python?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get information from the `<a>` tag in between these two span tags

```
<span class="mentioned">
<a class="mentioned-123" onclick="information('123');" href="#28669">&gt;&gt;28669</a>
</span>
```

For example I would like to be able to get the value of the `href` in it. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can look for the `mentioned-123` class and then access the `href` with:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
print(soup.find("a", class_="mentioned-123")["href"])
```